# comparison between void pointer, is it defined or compiler dependent?

Tags: c++, pointers

I tried to compare casting an int to void* that worked , even comparison between them

```
int i=1,j=2;
float a=1.1;

if((void *)i > (void *)j )
cout<<"i>j"<<endl;
else
cout<<"i<j"<<endl;
```

output was

```
i<j
```

but this

```
if((void *)a > (void *)i )
cout<<"a>i"<<endl;
else
cout<<"a<i"<<endl;
```

gives an error

```
 error: invalid cast from type ‘float’ to type ‘void*’
```

I thought we can cast any thing to void pointers?Is it not so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the address of "anything" (that's not a function or whose "address" is given by a pointer to member) to a `void *`. In addition, some integral types can be cast to pointers. I guess what you wanted to do is this

```
if((void *)&i > (void *)&j )
    cout<<"i>j"<<endl;
else
    cout<<"i<j"<<endl;
```

and that

```
if((void *)&a > (void *)&i )
    cout<<"a>i"<<endl;
else
    cout<<"a<i"<<endl;
```

However, notice that the results of such pointer comparisons are unspecified as per C++11 5.9/3 (as explained by [Mike Seymour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/204847/mike-seymour) in his [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18597546/1137388).

The best way to compare pointers of the same type is using the templates `greater`, `less`, `greater_equal` and `less_equal` because 20.8.5/8 says:

> > For templates `greater`, `less`, `greater_equal`, and `less_equal`, the specializations for any pointer type yield a total order, even if the built-in operators `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=` do not.

Therefore, you should use

```
if (std::greater<void*>()((void *) &i, (void *) &j))
    cout<<"i>j"<<endl;
else
    cout<<"i<j"<<endl;
```

Comment: Actually, only object pointer types.  (Not only function pointers but also pointer-to-members are excluded)

Comment: (that's not a function or whose "address" is given by a pointer to member)...that means only object  types not even pointer to a function...?But what is the problem in that if I can cast other addresses?

Comment: @ParagJain: See C++11 5.2.10/8: "Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa is conditionally-supported. The meaning of such a conversion is implementation-defined [...]"

Answer (score 5):

> comparison between void pointer, is it defined or compiler dependent?

That is well-defined, but the results are usually unspecified, as described by C++11 5.9/3: "If both pointers represent the same address or are both the null pointer value, the result is true if the operator is <= or >= and false otherwise; otherwise the result is unspecified."

Note that `std::less` and friends are required to define a total order for pointers, even if the built-in operators don't.

However, doing just about anything with pointers that you've converted from arbitrary integer values will give undefined behaviour.

> I thought we can cast any thing to void pointers?Is it not so?

No. `reinterpret_cast` (or an equivalent C-style cast) can convert between pointer and integer types. Converting a floating-point value to a pointer makes no sense at all.

Comment: ok "Converting a floating-point value to a pointer makes no sense at all."...what if somebody asking this question in an interview.So the answer should be it is not legal,?

Comment: @ParagJain: Correct. You could come up with a nonsensical but valid conversion sequence like `float -> int -> void*`, but the language does not define a direct `float->void*` conversion.

Comment: Don't understand the standared quote. false otherwise, otherwise unspecified?

Comment: @NeilKirk: "and false otherwise" = "and false if the operator is not <= or >=". "Otherwise unspecified" = "If both pointers *don't* represent the same address or are both the null pointer value, unspecified"

Comment: If you are curious why it is unspecified, read up on segmented memory models: with the freedom the C++ standard provides, pointer comparisons can be done *on the segment offset only* in some cases, and in others, you can just compare segment and offset instead of working out where in memory it is (segments can overlap).

Comment: @Yakk So if I take char pointer a and b = a + 1, cast to void and compare, it's not guaranteed that a < b?

Comment: @neilkirk That is guaranteed to work if and only if `a` was pointing at part of a data structure, and not `nullptr` or past-end. The addresses in each data structure, plus the address one-past-the-end, are valid addresses, and comparison within them is reasonable. If I did `char* buf=new char[10]; char* a = buf+10; b = a+1;` C++ does not guarantee that `b>a`, but it does guarantee that `a>buf`.  In fact, I think `a+1` may invoke undefined behavior (imagine if overflowing the segmented memory model segments can cause an overflow interrupt, and handling it has a performance penalty) technically.

Comment: @NeilKirk: If you cast to `void*` then the only specified behaviour is the quote in my answer; so there's no guarantee that `a<b` then. If you leave them as `char*`, then that is guaranteed *if* both pointers point to members of the same array (or one past the end). See C++11 5.9 if you want to know all the gory details.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I don't ;) I just never use void* if I can aVOID it!!??!

Answer (score 3):

> I thought we can cast any thing to void pointers?Is it not so?

A `void*` is intended to allow you to cast to and from *any object pointer type*, not *any type*.

This means you could do:

```
if((void *)&a > (void *)&i )
```

However, checking and comparing pointer values like this is very rarely useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast any *object pointer type* to `void*` not any type.

So you can solve your problem with:

```
if((void *)&a > (void *)&i )
//         ^            ^
```

**But comparing the address of two variables is not the same thing as comparing the values.** I don't think you will have the result you want... You will have *Undefined behaviour* here.

Comment: yes actually I made this mistake I should have noticed,I was trying to know about void pointers.thanks.